# Spring Kafka: Non-transactional producer callback handling

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using a non transactional producer and trying to understand how callbacks are handled for success/failure scenarios.

For a successful send, i see that the callback is executed by the kafka-producer-network-thread thread ("Sent ok" message).

**Successful send message - kafka-producer-network-thread 00:59:17.522**

```
00:59:16.850 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.3.1
00:59:16.858 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Sending: ProducerRecord(
00:59:16.863 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory - CloseSafeProducer 
00:59:17.326 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Sent
:::
00:59:17.522 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] TRACE o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Sent ok
```

I then simulate a failure by supplying a non existant topic name to the kafka template and this time the callback seemingly executed in Listener container thread ("Failed to send" message) followed by a "sent" message in Listener container thread!

How did the container thread log the "failed to send" message - its part of callback! After logging the failure message it then logged the sent message (part of doSend method in Kafka Template). Was the container thread blocked post send?

**Failed send message - KafkaListenerEndpointContainer 00:27:33.975 , sent message 00:27:33.982**

```
00:27:33.773 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Sending: ProducerRecord(
00:27:33.779 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory - CloseSafeProducer 
00:27:33.957 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test1=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
00:27:33.957 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Topic authorization failed for topics [test1]
00:27:33.958 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: BgLUXrqZSLKvOw2Kn0nhVQ
00:27:33.973 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message
:::
00:27:33.975 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Failed to send

00:27:33.977 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE 
o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory - CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@57033d15] close(PT5S)

00:27:33.982 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] TRACE o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate - Sent: ProducerRecord
```

The "sent ok" and "failed to send" messages are both logged in the buildCallback method of KafkaTemplate.

```
protected ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> doSend(final ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord) {

     producer.send(producerRecord, buildCallback(producerRecord, producer, future));
            if (this.autoFlush) {
                flush();
            }
            this.logger.trace(() -> "Sent: " + producerRecord);
            return future;
}

private Callback buildCallback
    return (metadata, exception) -> {
            try {
                if (exception == null) {
:::
                    KafkaTemplate.this.logger.trace(() -> "Sent ok: " + producerRecord + ", metadata: " + metadata);
                }
                else {
:::
                    KafkaTemplate.this.logger.debug(exception, () -> "Failed to send: " + producerRecord);
                }
```

Shouldnt the callback always be executed by producer-network-thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then simulate a failure by...

That's your problem - in order to send a request, the topic's metadata is needed.

> Error while fetching metadata

The calling thread blocks until metadata is available.

In this case the producer network thread reports the failure to get the metadata, not the failure to send, so the future is completed with the exception by the calling thread.

You need a real send failure. A couple of things to try:

- send a record that's too large for the broker to handle
- send a record when there are not enough in-sync replicas available

The first might be detected by the producer code, I don't recall.